# RPM build No such file or directory

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to create simple RPM file with many small files.

```
[root@laptop rpm]# tree
.
├── BUILD
├── BUILDROOT
├── RPMS
├── SOURCES
│   └── some_agent-1.0.tar.gz
├── SPECS
│   ├── kernel.spec
│   └── kernel.spec~
└── SRPMS

6 directories, 3 files
[root@laptop rpm]#
```

I have this spec file:

```
Summary: some_agent
Name: some_agent
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
License: Apache
Group: application
Source0: %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-buildroot
%description
Test 

%prep
%setup -q

%build


%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
make root=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT install

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc
agent/*
```

But when I try to build the RPM package I get this error:

```
[root@laptop ~]$ rpmbuild -bb -v ~/rpm/SPECS/kernel.spec
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.RUwFW5
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/rcbandit/rpm/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ cd /home/rcbandit/rpm/BUILD
+ rm -rf some_agent-1.0
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/rcbandit/rpm/SOURCES/some_agent-1.0.tar.gz
+ /bin/tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd some_agent-1.0
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.RUwFW5: line 38: cd: some_agent-1.0: No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.RUwFW5 (%prep)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.RUwFW5 (%prep)
[root@laptop ~]$ ^C
```

Do you have any idea where is my mistake?

I copied the source file but for some reason it's not found.

Comment: It looks like rpmbuild has some problems with changing directory to unpacked some_agent directory, check paths. Maybe your sources weren't compressed properly - without 'some_agent-1.0' directory, just files? Try to uncompress it manually and see what is the result.

Comment: No, manually uncompressing files is not solving the problem.

Comment: When you unpack the `some_agent-1.0.tar.gz` tarball, do you end up with a directory called `some_agent-1.0`? Or something else?

Comment: yes, which directory I have to unzip it? SOURCES?

Comment: Now the generated RPM is empty. Looks like again I'm missing something.

Comment: I reverted back to the original since there was an answer that (at least partly) answered that question already by the time you modified the question and invalidated their answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%install 
install -m 0755 -d %{buildroot}/opt/agent
cp -a your_milion_files/* %{buildroot}/opt/agent

%files 
/opt/agent
```

When you specify %dir, it will include just that directory and nothing else. Without %dir pragma, it will include that directory and EVERYTHING within it.
So you just to copy those files in that directory in %install section.

Edit:

Let say that some-agent-1.0.tar.gz contains:

```
agent/binary/agent.sh
agent/data/data1.dat
agent/data/data2.dat
....
agent/data/data1000.dat
agent/LICENSE
```

then your sections should be:

```
%install
install -m 0755 -d %{buildroot}/%{_bindir}/some-agent
install -m 0755 -d %{buildroot}/%{_datadir}/
cp -a binary/agent.sh %{buildroot}/%{_bindir}/some-agent
cp -a data/* %{buildroot}/%{_datadir}/

%files
%doc LICENSE
%{_bindir}/some-agent
%{_datadir}/some-agent
```

Instead of the last line you can either use:

```
%dir %{_datadir}/some-agent
%{_datadir}/some-agent/*
```

but obviously

```
 %{_datadir}/some-agent
```

is shorter and have the same meaning.

In that %install section you can use any bash command. So do there what would you normally do on command line. Any shell expansion works so use that to your advance.

I used some macros - you should use them rather then hardcoded path. You can get full list of available macros by

```
rpm --showrc
```

And evaluate them by

```
rpm --eval '%{_datadir}'
```

which on recent RHEL and Fedoras evaluato to

```
/usr/share
```

I also presented little trick with LICENSE file. When it is present in topmost directory of tarfile, then you just pass the name to %doc macro and rpm will place it to correct %docdir automatically.

Comment: I don't understand what I have to insert for `your_milion_files/*`? Maybe each file or specific directory?

Comment: In %prep section you correctly unpacked some-agent-1.0.tar.gz and at the beginning of %install section you are changed into ./agent/ directory, which should be topmost dirctory of your tar. So you basically copy those files to correct location in %{buildroot}. I will try to edit my answer and give specific example.

Comment: Should use ${SourceX} instead of %{buildroot}

Answer (score 8):

Look at the log from the build process.  First, `rpmbuild` changes into the `BUILD` directory:

```
+ cd /home/rcbandit/rpm/BUILD
```

Then it untars your source tarball:

```
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/rcbandit/rpm/SOURCES/some_agent-1.0.tar.gz
+ /bin/tar -xf -
```

Then it attempts to `cd` into the `some_agent-1.0` directory, which is presumably created by untarring the source archive:

```
+ cd some_agent-1.0
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.RUwFW5: line 38: cd: some_agent-1.0: No such file or directory
```

This is failing.  This suggests that unpacking the archive is not creating the directory RPM is looking for.  You would typically solve this using an argument to the `%setup` macro.  For example, if I have an archive named `some_agent-1.0.tar.gz`, and it contains:

```
an-unexpected-name/
an-unexpected-name/README
```

I would need to indicate that with the `-n` argument to the `%setup` macro:

```
%prep
%setup -q -n an-unexpected-name
```

Comment: @user1285928 If you unpack your some_agent-1.0.tar.gz, what do you get ? rpmbuild will assume it unpacks to a directory named some_agent-1.0, but from the output you show us, that is not the case. So, what's inside your tarball ?

Comment: I have a small progress. I have a directory agent into the tar.gz file which is a parent to many small files. I managed to build the RPM but it's empty. any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Your .spec files only create an empty directory in $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/agent , you would need to copy the files you want to be installed into there as well, and you probably need to remove the `%dir` in your `%install` section too.

Comment: Yes but I have 1000+ files into the package. I can't write every file name. Can you give me detailed information what I need to edit?

Comment: Perhaps just do `cp -ap agent/* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/agent/` Or instead of doing `install -m 0755 -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/agent` , just copy the whole directory tree: `install -m 0755 -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/ ` and `cp -R agent $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/`

Comment: I get cp: cannot stat `agent/*': No such file or directory

Comment: Run `pwd` in your spec file, then you will learn what the current working directory is in the %install section and discover that I made a mistake, and it should just be `cp -ap * $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/agent/` .

Comment: I tried to copy whole directory tree using cp -ap * $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/agent/ but I get + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars and the computer hangs. How I can run pwd into the spec file to see the location?

Comment: Thanks `%setup -q -n an-unexpected-name` was what I was searching for.